# Christoffel Symbols for a Perturbed Metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory

If a metric $g$ is given by the sum of a background metric $g_B$ and a perturbation $h$ ie. $g_{ij} = g_{Bij} + h_{ij}$, then the *difference* of the Christoffel symbols for the background metric and the perturbing part can be written as a tensor which is equal (at first order perturbations) to

$$\frac{1}{2}g_{B}^{cd}(\partial_a h_{bd} + \partial_b h_{ad} - \partial_d h_{ab}) .$$

If, however, one wishes to have the Christoffel symbols for the actual perturbed metric rather than the difference of the Christoffel symbols, does this mean one has to add the above expression to the expression for the Christoffel symbols of the original base metric?

Comment: There should be a perturbation term from inverse of total metric as well, which can combine with the derivative combination of the background metric. Note that the expression you have written is only true if your background metric is Minkowskian in Cartesian coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be seen that $\Gamma_{abc}$ is the sum of $\Gamma_{B,abc}$ plus the perturbation term. But as KP99 commented, as $g^{ij}$ differs from $g^{ij}_B$ with a first-order term $-h^{ij}=-g_B^{im}h_{mn}g_B^{jn}$, the perturbation should have included another term like $-h^{cd}\Gamma_{B,abd}$, unless $\Gamma_B$ is a near-zero term, which is not true for an arbitrary coordinate system even with a flat background metric.

Comment: Do you mean the total perturbation term (assuming only first order perturbations) should be $$\frac{1}{2}g_{B}^{cd}(\partial_a h_{bd} + \partial_b h_{ad} - \partial_d h_{ab}) - \frac{1}{2}h^{cd}(\partial_a g_{B,bd} + \partial_b g_{B,ad} - \partial_d g_{B,ab})?$$

Comment: Exactly. The second term is what the background connection expression would have contributed to the first-order approximation.